# How to use StreamReader in .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-rc2

I am using dotnet core version `1.0.0-preview2-1-003177` in inside of Visual Studio Code C# Sharp project.

I am not sure how to use `StreamReader` class. Visual Studio Code IntelliSense only provides `System.IO.Compression` & `System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles` and not `System.IO.StreamReader`.

I am sure I'll have to add it to dependency in project.json but I'm not sure what version and how

```
"dependencies": {
    "System.IO.StreamReader": "--here--"
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the [System.IO](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO) nuget package.
The latest version is 4.3.0.

Don't forget add the correct using statment `using System.IO;`.